# warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, отладка, qtcreator

Ubuntu 16.04 x64 
Не удаётся дебажить проект.

Скачал новый Qt через онлайн установочник qt-unified-linux-x64-2.0.3-online.run (qt 5.9.2, qtcreator 4.4.1). Установил gdb 7.12, создал тестовый QWidget проект:

```
Debugging starts
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
&"Cannot exec  -c exec /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt_new/myprog/test/src/build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/test .\n"
&"Error: No such file or directory\n"
Debugging has finished
```

Попытка через консоль:

```
gdb '/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/test/src2/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled' 

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/test/src2/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled...done.
(gdb) 
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/test/src2/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled 
Cannot exec  -c exec /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/test/src2/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled .
Error: Нет такого файла или каталога
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

Воспользовался [командой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621447/ubuntu-debugging-in-clion-exits-with-code-127):

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

Результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

**Для консольной версии gdb**

```
export SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Прописав в ~/.bashrc и перезагрузившись gdb отработал запуск без ошибок.

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

До этого команда выдавала пустую строку.

**В QtCreator проблема осталась**

Tools\Options\Build & Run\Kits\Debbuger

установил новый деббагер

Projects\Build Environment

Присвоил переменной SHELL значение /bin/sh

пока безрезультатно.